# Finding all classes with Kotlin JS

Tags: javascript, oop, kotlin

I can do this with no problems using Kotlin for JVM, but how to get all Kotlin classes with Kotlin for JS? I need to list all my classes inside a list, like this.

```
document.querySelector("#debugger-filter").let{
    all_kotlin_classes_on_my_application.forEach{k -> it?.innerHTML += "<li>${k.simpleName}</li>\n"}
}
```

Comment: All classes within what scope?

Comment: I'm sorry. Scopes? Are you talking about packages or something else?